# Django Template being rendered differently for different urls

Tags: django, templates

I'm using STATIC_URL in one of my templates and it works properly if I use one url and fails if I use another. In both cases, the exact same view is being run with the exact same template.

Template code:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/form.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- rest of page... -->
```

View code:

```
def myform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        obj = save_form(form)
        if obj:
            send_confirmation_email(obj)
            return redirect('done-page')
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form,})
```

Urls

```
# site urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'site.app.views.myform'),
    url(r'^app/', include('site.app.urls'),
    #...
)

# app urls.py
urlpatterns('site.app.views',
    url(r'^$', 'myform'),
    #...
)
```

The above is a snippet of my django site. If the page is accessed via "mydomain.com/" (the index of the site), STATIC_URL is rendered properly and the css file is linked properly. If the page is accessed via "mydomain.com/app/" (the index of app), STATIC_URL becomes blank and, hence no css, but the rest of the page renders properly.

I was under the impression that if the views and templates are the same, the url should be irrelevant. Am I missing something? What must I change to allow STATIC_URL to render properly regardless of the url used?

Comment: What does the source of the two files output the full path as? Is the one `/static/css/form.css`, and the other `css/form.css` ?

Comment: Yes, that is the output. At root, I get '/static/css/form.css' and in app/ I get 'css/form.css'

Comment: Have you tried Django debug toolbar, to maybe help infer what's happening? Based on the information you gave, I don't think that should be happening - maybe there's some external factor? In any case, this is interesting enough that I'll set up a test case if you don't find anything by tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. The strange behavior occurred because this was a copy of a previously built django site. I overlooked the first argument of urlpatterns in app/urls.py, leaving the code pointing to an older version. Unfortunately, that code lived on the same box and was on the python path. Thus, the mistake failed to cause an exception and, instead, sinisterly did something I wasn't expecting.

The actual scenario looked like this:

```
# site_copy urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'site_copy.app.views.myform'),
    url(r'^app/', include('site_copy.app.urls'),
    #...
)

# site_copy/app urls.py
urlpatterns('site.app.views',
    url(r'^$', 'myform'),
    #...
)
```

Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I find it hard to believe that `STATIC_URL` "becomes blank". There's no rational reason for this unless the offending view response was cached from a time when `STATIC_URL` literally had no value. If you are employing view or template caching make sure you delete the cache, or similar restart memcached (or other). If you're in development and using `runserver`, restart `runserver`.

The other more likely scenario based on when it does and doesn't work, is that your `STATIC_URL` is not prefixed with a `/`, i.e. it's just `static/`. That would make the link to the CSS file `/static/css/forms.css` on the homepage (as it should be), but it would be `/app/static/css/forms.css` on the other page, which is obviously not correct.

Comment: I believe Chris has nailed it on the head in his second paragraph. Do a view source at both urls in your browser and have a look at the url that is being output for that css file.

Comment: Unfortunately, the situation the is the former. `STATIC_URL` does appear to be empty in the app url. The source from the html is as below:

From 'mydomain.com/', I get:
`<link href="/static/app/css/form.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

while from 'mydomain.com/app/', I get:
`<link href="app/css/form.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

where my STATIC_URL is set to '/static/'.

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing here, but it could be because you're not passing a `ContextObject` in your view. So to fix this, you'd do this:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

...

def myform(request):
    ...

    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Otherwise the `STATIC_URL` variable will not be passed to the template, and be blank, as you described. I also assume you already have this in your Context Processors setting:

```
django.core.context_processors.static
```

Comment: The `render` shortcut automatically uses a RequestContext. `render_to_request` is the version that requires it to be set explicitly. And yes, the static processor is included in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Comment: Ah you are right, it says so right in the docs, my mistake. Hmm, what else could it be...